# How to make Amazon S3 and SFTP requests using pure REST services?

Tags: python, rest, amazon-s3, sftp

I have a Python script that I want to upload to our server so that it can run every day, and part of the script's function is to download a file from an SFTP connection, do some work on it and upload it to our Amazon S3 bucket.* However, I want my program to be as lean as possible so that it doesn't mess with the other daily tasks we have on the server, so I want to use only REST services and not import anything. I want to get my requests working in a REST client (I've been using Insomnia) before I put them into code.

I've searched high and low to find tutorials for how to do this, but I've found nothing. Amazon's S3 docs say things like: "Request syntax: GET / HTTP/1.1", but that doesn't tell me anything about how to actually make the request or even what URL to use to make the request to.

Can anyone give me some guidance (or at least a URL)? Thanks!

*Edit: As pointed out by Martin Prikryl in the comments, I cannot make SFTP requests using REST. I still want to find out how to make S3 requests though.

Comment: You cannot make SFTP requests using REST.

Comment: Regarding the S3: It's pretty broad and complex question. Do not expect 20 lines of code. As such I do not think this is suitable question for Stack OVerflow. Why don't you take some Python S3 library (https://pypi.org/project/s3/) and extract/reuse its code?